# Improving performance of drawing Tiled bitmaps in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a way to improve the performance of some drawing I am doing. Currently it is a 32x32 grid of tiles that I am drawing. Using the following code to draw onto the drawing context

```
for (int x = startX; x < endX; x++)
        {
            for (int y = startY; y < endY; y++)
            {
                dg.Children.Add(
                    new ImageDrawing(_mapTiles[GameWorldObject.GameMap[x, y].GraphicsTile.TileStartPoint],
                        new Rect(CountX * 8, CountY * 8, 8, 8)
                        ));

                dg.Children.Add(
                    new GeometryDrawing(
                        null,
                        new Pen(
                            new SolidColorBrush(
                                Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 20)), .3), 
                                new RectangleGeometry(
                                    new Rect(CountX * 8, CountY * 8, 8, 8)
                                )
                            )
                        );

                CountY++;
            }
            CountY = 0;
            CountX++;
        }

        dc.DrawDrawing(dg);
```

The Image I am drawing is a CachedBitmap. Even using a CachedBitmap, I still have a delay of about a half second each time I need to redraw the Canvas.

Not sure if there is a more performant way to handle drawing to this grid. Eventually I want to expand control to function as a mini-map, so I need to keep that in mind.

Also, I tried previously to just draw each bitmap directly to the drawing context but that seems a bit slower.

Comment: For a 32x32 grid I found your method to be fast, I can post a solution using a WriteableBitmap that would work well for small tiles like the 8px squares in the code you posted. Is the code for `GameWorldObject.GameMap[x, y].GraphicsTile.TileStartPoint` just a simple access? and is it a 32x32 grid with 8px sized tiles that is performing slow?

Comment: _maptiles is a dictionary that contains all of the possible bitmaps. its a 32x32 grid that I am shrinking down from its original size. The tiles are actually 64x64. I wonder if it would be faster to shrink a single image after its built rather than each image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added DrawingGroup.Freeze() before drawing, and it seemed to help with the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If it's mostly static minimap draw it into an Image, and draw that image. Or you can do a big image, where you draw the whole map into it, and just draw the current visible part of it.

**Edit**: And maybe [this blog post](http://beta.blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/janiv/archive/2009/06/07/hardware-acceleration-in-wpf.aspx) worth a check, whether you are drawing it with software or hardware acceleration on.

Comment: The problem here is that this is an editor, and the minimap can change as things are being edited. If the map wasn't so large, then this would be an acceptable solution. However, the map is too large to just draw a static image and update it anytime there is a change.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example using WriteableBitmap, the performance of this is mainly related to the size of the whole map whereas your original method is more dependent on the amount of tiles. You could alter it to have an alpha-blended border between the tiles but leaving a gap between them would be easier and more performant. You won't need the code randomising the tiles but you should have some dirty flag so you only redraw the bitmap when its changed.

You may also want to look my answer and the others to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668181/drawing-a-grid-of-images-with-wpf/5785072#5785072). That said you don't have as many items and 32x32 using your method wasn't slow for me.

```
<local:Map x:Name="map" />
<RepeatButton Click="Button_Click" Content="Change" />
```

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    map.seed++;
    map.InvalidateVisual();
}
```

```
public class Map : FrameworkElement
{
    private int[][] _mapTiles;

    public Map()
    {
        _mapTiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures", "*.jpg").Select(x =>
        {
            var b = new BitmapImage(new Uri(x));
            var transform = new TransformedBitmap(b, new ScaleTransform((1.0 / b.PixelWidth)*tileSize,(1.0 / b.PixelHeight)*tileSize));
            var conv = new FormatConvertedBitmap(transform, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null, 0);
            int[] data = new int[tileSize * tileSize];
            conv.CopyPixels(data, tileSize * 4, 0);
            return data;
        }).ToArray();

        bmp = new WriteableBitmap(w * tileSize, h * tileSize, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);
        destData = new int[bmp.PixelWidth * bmp.PixelHeight];
    }

    const int w = 64, h = 64, tileSize = 8;
    public int seed = 72141;
    private int oldSeed = -1;
    private WriteableBitmap bmp;
    int[] destData;

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        if(seed != oldSeed)
        {
            oldSeed = seed;
            int startX = 0, endX = w;
            int startY = 0, endY = h;
            Random rnd = new Random(seed);

            for(int x = startX; x < endX; x++)
            {
                for(int y = startY; y < endY; y++)
                {
                    var tile = _mapTiles[rnd.Next(_mapTiles.Length)];
                    var rect = new Int32Rect(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
                    for(int sourceY = 0; sourceY < tileSize; sourceY++)
                    {
                        int destY = ((rect.Y + sourceY) * (w * tileSize)) + rect.X;
                        Array.Copy(tile, sourceY * tileSize, destData, destY, tileSize);
                    }
                }
            }

            bmp.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, w * tileSize, h * tileSize), destData, w * tileSize * 4, 0);
        }

        dc.DrawImage(bmp,new Rect(0,0,w*tileSize,h*tileSize));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this probably won't work. The overall map is just to large. Thats the reason I had to tile the map to begin with.

Comment: It took 35ms for a grid with 200 by 200 tiles of 8px each. With 64 tiles 8px in size it should be fast enough. You can run the code I posted without changing it to see how it performs for you.

Comment: Try something more along the lines of 50,000x50,000 tiles and see how it performs. This is what I meant by there being too many tiles. Your bitmap would hit a memory limit wall, and it would be extremely slow to render the first time. Some hybrid method of this might work, but it would be slow and complicated.

Comment: Oh I see, that's only about 2.5 million times bigger than the original question :D Your talking gigs of data even before you've looked at displaying anything. My other answer I linked to can handle 2000 by 2000 maybe putting those in a virtualizing panel would be a start but I'd read up on stuff like Deep Zoom and MegaTexture.

Comment: Filling the Virtualized Canvas from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/03/08/performant-virtualized-wpf-canvas.aspx with lots of the above or the alternate method I got to 50k. My data was randomly generated I didn't look into how store that many tiles as that's a different question. That canvas has a quad tree implementation which might be useful.

Comment: Sorry, my question was a bit ambiguous. I am only displaying a 32x32 grid of tiles, but underlying that is a very large grid of tiles.